# Padrino route optional parameter

Tags: ruby, padrino

I am trying to do some tricks with routes. And I need to use optional route parameter in Padrino. I googled that solution for this are "()" parenthesis. I couldn't find in docs.

But when I try to use

```
get :sort, :with => [:order, :asc, '(:search)'] do
```

them, mustermann is giving me classic error for missing parameter

```
cannot expand with keys [:asc, :order], possible expansions: [:asc, :order, :search]
```

when I try to call

```
url(:sbirka, :sort, :order => "id", :asc => @asc)
```

I also tried different style

```
get :sort, "/:order/:asc/(:search)" do
```

with the same result

Please any suggestions how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since Padrino is based on Sinatra, every routing pattern possible with Sinatra should be possible in Padrino as well. From [Sinatra's excellent README file](http://sinatrarb.com/intro.html), introductory 'Routes' section:

> Route patterns may have optional parameters

In your case, assuming `:search` is optional, I would try:

```
get '/:order/:asc/:search?' do
  # your  code
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I will try, it is working like route, I must change my url helpers for sinatra style, padrino style url(:sbirka, :sort,  :order => "country", :asc => @asc) does not work, I will write as soon as I will try

Comment: It is not working :( If I use :search? as in example, I get 404 not found, when I put :search? away, it is working.